# Problem with fetching JSON file using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Good Day,

I am having a problem fetching my `JSON` file using Android Studio. How can I call a specific `JSONObject` for example on my code below I want to know if the inputted phone number is equals to the `JSONObject` number. I am trying to read the `JSONArray` and store in individually on different strings.

Every time I am trying to call `obj.getString("phonenum")` inside the loop the only value I am getting is the last value.

My code are as follow.

JSON File.

GetInfo.php

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Angelo Dayao",
    "email": "angelo@gmail.com",
    "phonenum": "639201234567"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Angelo Dayao",
    "email": "angelogg@g.com",
    "phonenum": "639161234567"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Anna Chelzia",
    "email": "anna@g.com",
    "phonenum": "639771234567"
  }
]
```

JAVA FILE Code

```
public void GetData(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                try {
                                    JSONObject obj = null;

                                    obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    if(obj.getString("phonenum") == phonenumber){
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("phonenum"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

Comment: *I am getting is the last value.* Please remove this line from there and paste before for loop `JSONObject obj = null;` also try @Md.Asaduzzaman comment.

Comment: Instead of `==`, use `equals` to compare String. Also try to check by *debugging* instead of showing `toast`

Comment: instead of "obj.getString("phonenum") == phonenumber" use "obj.getString("phonenum").equals(phonenumber)"

Comment: Thank You everyone! It actually works! My bad for calling a null inside the loop did not realize it!!